# ¿como solucionar problema con reflex?

Tags: python

He estado aprendiendo reflex y me encontre con el primer ejemplo que se muestra ene l tutorial, cuando lo quiero usar, en mi entorno no funciona, es decir, ejecuta bien en la web pero los contadores no funcionan, este es el codigo:

```
class State(rx.State):
    count: int = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.count += 1

    def decrement(self):
        self.count -= 1


def index():
    return rx.hstack(
        rx.button(
            "Decrement",
            bg="#fef2f2",
            color="#b91c1c",
            border_radius="lg",
            on_click=State.decrement,
        ),
        rx.heading(State.count, font_size="2em"),
        rx.button(
            "Increment",
            bg="#ecfdf5",
            color="#047857",
            border_radius="lg",
            on_click=State.increment,
        ),
        spacing="1em",
    )


app = rx.App()
app.add_page(index)
app.compile()
```

asi se ve en el idle (es pycharm):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi se ve en el navegador (chrome):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con “no funciona bien”?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.